# Как можно ускорить код python?

Tags: python

Есть парсер, но выводит он не всегда и медленно работает, как можно поправить и ускорить?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import urllib.request
import time
import re
import sys
import requests

regex = r"price_85d2b9c\s+\w+\D+(?P<price>\d+\s+\d+)"

class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self,url):
        global app
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
        
    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        self.loadFinished(bool)
        print("Load Finished")

    def Callable(self,data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://www.aviasales.ru/search/PEE0712MOW23121?request_source=search_form&expected_price_currency=rub&expected_price_source=calendar"
client_response = Client(url)
#print(client_response.html)
test_str = client_response.html

prices = []
        
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    #print("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
        prices.append("{group}".format(group = match.group(groupNum)))
#print(prices)
```

Comment: А вы разбирались - что именно у вас тормозит?

Comment: Можно запустить на более быстром компьютере

Answer (score 0):

***Данный ответ сформулирован Искусственный интеллектом. Возможны ошибки!***

Есть несколько вещей, которые вы можете сделать, чтобы улучшить производительность и вывод этого скрипта.

Во-первых, вы можете использовать метод findall модуля re для поиска всех совпадений с регулярным выражением вместо использования метода finditer и перебора совпадений. Это сделает код более эффективным и сократит время, необходимое для поиска совпадений.

Во-вторых, вы можете использовать метод search модуля re, чтобы найти первое совпадение с регулярным выражением, а затем использовать метод group для извлечения совпадающей группы вместо использования метода finditer и перебора групп совпадений. Это сделает код проще и эффективнее.

В-третьих, вы можете использовать функцию time.perf_counter для измерения времени, необходимого для поиска совпадений и извлечения группы, а затем распечатать время в конце скрипта. Это поможет вам увидеть, сколько времени требуется скрипту для запуска, и определить любые узкие места в коде.

Вот пример того, как вы можете изменить код, чтобы сделать его более эффективным и более согласованным:

```
import time
import re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage

class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

regex = r"price_85d2b9c\s+\w+\D+(?P<price>\d+\s+\d+)"
url = "https://www.aviasales.ru/search/PEE0712MOW23121?request_source=search_form&expected_price_currency=rub&expected_price_source=calendar"

start = time.perf_counter()

client_response = Client(url)
html = client_response.html

match = re.search(regex, html)
if match:
    price = match.group("price")
    print(f"Price: {price}")
else:
    print("No match found")

end = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Time taken: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: Спасибо, а вы не знаете случаем в чём может быть проблема, что код не каждый раз выводит price?

Comment: @qqStardy не могу утверждать конкретно, но возможно она просто не находит значение price для данного блока. соответственно не может его вывести

Comment: Это я понял, проблема в том что Client не всегда находит полный html, может вы сможете помочь с этим?

Comment: В добавок к этому нужен именно finditer, так как нужны именно позиции и порядок.